# useEffect not working when trying to fetch information

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I´m trying to fetch user information and show it to the page but when I go to the page it is completely blank and with errors saying that cannot read properties that are null. So I put console.log when it is suppose to fetch and it never shows, which is why I realized that the function inside the useEffect is not being called and I really don't know why.

```js
  function User() {

  const[userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState(null);
  const {user, checkAuth} = useContext(UserContext);
  const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);
  const params = useParams();

  function logout() {
    axios.post('http://localhost:3030/logout', {}, {withCredentials: true})
      .then(() => {
        checkAuth().catch(() => setRedirect(true));
      });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    function getUserInfo() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:3030/users/'+params.id)
        .then(response => {
          setUserInfo(response.data);
          console.log('here'); //this never shows in the console

        });
    }
    getUserInfo();
  }, [params.id]);

  if (redirect) {
    return (<Navigate to={'/'} />);
  }
 
  return (
    <main>
    <Container>
        <ContainerHeader>
            <StyledHeader>Profile</StyledHeader>
            {!!userInfo && !!user && parseInt(params.id) === user.id && (
            <LinksRow>
            <EditLinkButton to={'/profile'}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEdit} />  Edit</EditLinkButton>
            <Button onClick={() => logout()}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faArrowRight} />  Logout</Button>
            </LinksRow>
            )}
        </ContainerHeader>
        
        <Img src={ProfileImg} alt=""/>
        <Name>{userInfo.first_name} {userInfo.last_name}</Name>
        <Role>{userInfo.role}</Role>
        <Role>{userInfo.sector}</Role>
        <Labels><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEnvelope}/> {userInfo.email}</Labels>
        <Labels> <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faLocationDot} /> {userInfo.location} </Labels>
        <Labels>
            <Links href={userInfo.link} target="_blank"> <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faExternalLink} /> {userInfo.link}</Links>
        </Labels>
        <Labels> <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCoins} /> 100 CxCoins</Labels>
        <SecondHeader>Statistics</SecondHeader>
        <Labels> <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faComment} /> 100 comments</Labels>
        <Labels> <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTicket} /> 100 tickets</Labels>
              
    </Container>
    </main>
    
  );
}

export default User
```

Thank you!

Comment: It's probably because you are getting an error that should be handled with `catch`

Comment: hi friend! I changed to: ```function getUserInfo() {
      axios.get('http://localhost:3030/users/'+params.id)
        .then(response => {
          setUserInfo(response.data);
        })
        .catch(e =>console.log(e));
    }
    getUserInfo();
  }, [params.id]); ``` 

and it still won't show anything

Comment: Are you sure that this `useEffect` even runs? - Try adding `console.log` Have you checked network tab to see if the request is sent?

Comment: Yes, I have checked the network and it doesn't even send the request. It sent a couple of times before when I shut down everything and reopened. But then when I refresh or try to go to the page again it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Maybe `params.id` isn't what you expected, so it doesn't change, so the useEffect never runs?

Comment: @James I put it to print on the console and it is what I expect it to be :( which is the id of the current user logged in.

Comment: What if you add `console.log('effect ran');`as the first line of code inside the `useEffect` handler function?

Comment: Hi! It doesn't show also. I put in right before the axios line.

Comment: Right before the axios line or right before the `function getUserInfo() {` line? Try it right before the `function getUserInfo() {` line but still inside the `useEffect`.

Comment: I've tried both! Nothing shows :(

Comment: Try adding a simpler `useEffect` like `useEffect(() => { console.log('simple effect ran') }, []);`.

Comment: Also try adding `console.log('after useEffect setup');` just before `if (redirect) {` just as a sanity check to make sure your component is actually getting called.

Comment: It doesn't show the simple effect ran but it shows the after useEffect setup

Comment: Ok, very strange... thx for doing the tests and reporting back.

Comment: Any chance `redirect` is `true` and thus redirecting before `useEffect` has a chance to run?

Comment: If not, you might try commenting out the whole `User` component function and, just to test it out, instead put `function User() { useEffect(() => console.log('basic effect ran'), []); return (<div>Test</div>); }` and see if the effect runs in that simplest possible case.

Comment: If I remove everything that calls userInfo it shows the page! And also shows the console log from the useEffect

Comment: Nice! Sounds like you've got hold of a good lead. Maybe if you make all the references to `userInfo` in your JSX conditional on `userInfo` being truthy, that'll solve it?

Comment: omg @RockySims!!! Thank you so much!!! It works now! I put a lot of console logs and realized that there was never an error, it always went throught the then() everywhere, but it looked like a loop where the userInfo was null two times in a row then it would be ok after. So by putting {userInfo && (... fixed it :)) Thank you so much for helping and also teaching how to find errors :)

Answer (score 3):

1. The API maybe throwing an error, so you code never enters then block. You need to add a catch block and render some ui with the error data or redirect user elsewhere or show a toaster etc... If you want to show a ui, you can add an error state to your component
2. Until the API fetching the data for you, your `userInfo` is null, so you cant access for eg. `userInfo.first_name`. The component throws a rendering error, hence the useEffect never has a chance to run which would run had the rendering was completed successfully. Follow below code where I wait for userInfo to have some data on it before I access any of it's keys
3. You can alsoconsider adding a loading state to your Component

   ```
    function User() {      
      const[userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState(null);
      const {user, checkAuth} = useContext(UserContext);
      const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);
   const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
   const [error, setError] = useState(false);


      const params = useParams();

      function logout() {
        axios.post('http://localhost:3030/logout', {}, {withCredentials: true})
          .then(() => {
            checkAuth().catch(() => setRedirect(true));
          });
      }

      useEffect(() => {
        function getUserInfo() {
   setIsLoading(true)       axios.get('http://localhost:3030/users/'+params.id)
            .then(response => {
              setUserInfo(response.data);
              console.log('here'); //this never shows in the console

            })
    .catch(err=>setError(err?.message)) 
    .finally(() =>setIsLoading(false)) 
        }
        getUserInfo();
      }, [params.id]);

      if (redirect) {
        return (<Navigate to={'/'} />);
      }
    if (isLoading) {
        return (<Loader />);
      }

      return (
        <main>
        <Container>
            <ContainerHeader>
                <StyledHeader>Profile</StyledHeader>
                {!!userInfo && !!user && parseInt(params.id) === user.id && (
                <LinksRow>
                <EditLinkButton to={'/profile'}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEdit} />  Edit</EditLinkButton>
                <Button onClick={() => logout()}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faArrowRight} />  Logout</Button>
                </LinksRow>
                )}
            </ContainerHeader>
    {error && <Error error={error}/> 
   {!error &&  Object.keys(userInfo).length>0 && (  <>
            <Img src={ProfileImg} alt=""/>
            <Name>{userInfo.first_name} {userInfo.last_name}</Name>
            <Role>{userInfo.role}</Role>
            <Role>{userInfo.sector}</Role>
            <Labels><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEnvelope}/> {userInfo.email}</Labels>
            <Labels> <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faLocationDot} /> {userInfo.location} </Labels>
            <Labels>
                <Links href={userInfo.link} target="_blank"> <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faExternalLink} /> {userInfo.link}</Links>
            </Labels>
            <Labels> <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCoins} /> 100 CxCoins</Labels>
            <SecondHeader>Statistics</SecondHeader>
            <Labels> <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faComment} /> 100 comments</Labels>
            <Labels> <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTicket} /> 100 tickets</Labels>

   </>) 
   }               
        </Container>
        </main>

      );
    }

    export default User
   ```

Comment: thank you so much! it was an error worth of a noob afterall, but I really appreciate your comment because I got to learn new things :)

Answer (score 0):

Move getUserInfo method to outside of the userEffect hook.Then it may be work.

Comment: I've tried but it stays the same :(

Comment: Why would it not work?

Comment: Check whether there is a exception by adding catch block.

Comment: I did but it doesn't show in the console.

Comment: That mean parama.id value not ge tchange to rerender.

Comment: I think it does because I put console.log(params.id) in the container and it shows on the console